# KDEConnect Indicator in Ubuntu 16.04 does not show up

Tags: indicator, kde-connect

I have installed kdeconnect along with the indicator and I have noticed that the indicator does not work in ubuntu 16.04 with unity. I have tried to launch it from dash and terminal unsuccessfully. 
Based on my troubleshooting I have realised that the OS does not install the required dependencies that would have normally installed in ubuntu 14.04.
Does anybody knows how to make the indicator to work on ubuntu 16.04?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same happens in my Ubuntu-MATE 16.04. Can you add the output of the command `indicator-kdeconnect` to your question? Mine is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23082514/.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried installing on Ubuntu 16.04 but I have on Linux Mint 18 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04. I found that I have to install the kdeconnect-plasma package (which brings a LOT of dependencies with it) to get KDEConnect working.

For those who may not know, open a terminal & type

```
apt install kdeconnect-plasma
```

You may have to run the command as root like this

```
sudo apt install kdeconnect-plasma
```

Comment: Done that already and it's not working. The devices can ping each others but the indicator does not show up in unity.

Answer (score 1):

I got results by finding the [most recently updated fork](https://github.com/albertvaka/indicator-kdeconnect) of [the github project](https://github.com/vikoadi/indicator-kdeconnect) for indicator-kdeconnect, and building and installing it from that source.

Comment: I have compiled it but still, the indicator is not working. Thanks anyway...

Comment: I just have to mention, that indicator shows only when the phone is connected/in range