# indicator-kdeconnect is working, but without the indicator in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, kde, xfce, indicator, kde-connect

This is probably a repeat of [KDEConnect Indicator in Ubuntu 16.04 does not show up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762653/kdeconnect-indicator-in-ubuntu-16-04-does-not-show-up), but I'm hoping that if I ask the question better, it's more likely someone can help answer it. I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.1 Xenial, with Xfce as my desktop environment.

I've got KDEConnect and indicator-kdeconnect installed. indicator-kdeconnect isn't showing an indicator in my toolbar, and I would like it to. I can tell that it's working, because I get notifications on the screen from my phone when I get text messages.¹ I just don't get any of the features the indicator would provide (eg. showing battery life, or letting me interact with my phone).

I have both the "Indicator Plugin" and "Notification Area" widgets installed on my toolbar, and they're both showing other program icons just fine.

In my Xfce settings → Session and Startup → Advanced configuration, I have both "Launch GNOME services on startup" and "Launch KDE services on startup" checked. Konsole launches and runs for me fine, so I know I can run KDE applications.

When I run indicator-kdeconnect from the command line, it starts up and doesn't return me to the command line, so I know it isn't crashing. It shows this output on startup:

```
** Message: KDEConnectManager.vala:32: KDE Connect daemon found
** Message: Device.vala:73: device : /modules/kdeconnect/devices/e13f49345f45e663
** Message: Device.vala:263: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'isReachable' in interface 'org.kde.kdeconnect.device' at object path '/modules/kdeconnect/devices/e13f49345f45e663' (signature '')
```

The final line repeats three more times at startup, and after a long period of time, may repeat occasionally from there.

¹ I actually get one of two different types of notification, seemingly random as to which it will be. I'll either get a standard black Unity notification bubble in the upper-right corner of my screen, or a gray rectangle message across the top center of my screen. I suspect that one of these is from kdeconnectd and the other is from indicator-kdeconnect, but I don't know which is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using kdeconect 1.0 you will have problems because the dbus calls change on it.  After a long time without any change on indicator-kdeconnect I decided fix it,  you can download and compile it from   https://github.com/Bajoja/indicator-kdeconnect

Comment: Giving some instructions also would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the github project for indicator-kdeconnect, and found that there's a [reasonably modern fork](https://github.com/albertvaka/indicator-kdeconnect). I built that from source, and now I have an indicator that works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [indicator-kdeconnect](https://github.com/Bajoja/indicator-kdeconnect) package.
2. Unzip the package.
3. Access the `indicator-kdeconnect-master/data/icons/` folder.
4. Copy all folders to `/usr/share/icons`
5. Restart your computer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! We’re an English-only community, so we’d like to ask you to please translate your post to English. Otherwise your post will likely be deleted as "not an answer".